# Pull specific rows

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

Let's say that I have a data frame that looks like this...

```
City <- c("x","x","y","y","z","z","a","a")
Number <-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

mat <- cbind.data.frame(City ,Number)

"City"  "Number"
     x          1
     x          2  
     y          3
     y          4
     z          5
     z          6
     a          7
     a          8
```

Now I want to be able to pull the data for...

```
list <- c("x","y", "a")
```

And the desired out come would look something like this...

```
x  y a 
1  3 7 
2  4 8
```

I tried using which(list%in%City) to help find the indices to pull that data from the index but that does not produce the rows that I want.

**UPDATE**

Make sure that when you are using Chris' answer that your data type for "City" is "chr" otherwise you will pop up with an error message as I got originally before using the "as.character" function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I renamed your variable `list` to `test`, because `list` is a function name. You can do this, using `data.table`:

```
matdt <- as.data.table(mat)
setkey(matdt, City)
sapply(test, function(x) matdt[x, Number])
     x y a
[1,] 1 3 7
[2,] 2 4 8
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response. This works beautifully and is very concise.

Comment: How would I get this code to work if Number now is not an "int" type but a "numeric" type.

Comment: I am getting an error "i has not evaluated to logical, integer or double" when attempting to do it on a larger dataset.

Comment: Please post code showing exactly what you have done and the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the City names to the extraction function one by one. In this case sapply will deliver a matrix as you expect but if there were a varying number of results per city, the retruned object would be a list rather than a matrix:

```
sapply( list, function(city) mat[ mat$City %in% city, "Number"] )
     x y a
[1,] 1 3 7
[2,] 2 4 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
mat %>%
  filter(City %in% c("x", "y", "a")) %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  mutate(Index = 1:n()) %>%
  spread(City, Number) %>%
  select(-Index)
```