# Matching Multiple Rows To Find A Value - R

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I think that this is similiar but it is not the same as a previous question that I have asked here [Pull specific rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278008/pull-specific-rows)

Here is the code that I am now working with:

```
City <- c("x","x","y","y","z","z")
Type <- c("a","b","a","b","a","b")
Value <- c(1,3,2,5,6,10)
cbind.data.frame(City,Type,Value)
```

Which produces:

```
    City Type Value
1    x    a     1
2    x    b     3
3    y    a     2
4    y    b     5
5    z    a     6
6    z    b    10
```

I want to do something similar as before but now if two different conditions must be met to pull a specific number. Lets say we had a matrix,

```
testmat <- matrix(c("x","x","y","a","b","b"),ncol=2)
```

Which looks like this:

```
    [,1] [,2]
[1,] "x"  "a" 
[2,] "x"  "b" 
[3,] "y"  "b"
```

The desired outcome is

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "x"  "a"   1 
[2,] "x"  "b"   3 
[3,] "y"  "b"   5
```

**Another Question PLEASE ANSWER THIS PART**

```
City <- c("x","x","x","x","y","y","x","z")
Type <- c("a","a","a","a","a","b","a","b")

Value <- c(1,3,2,5,6,10,11,15)

mat <- cbind.data.frame(City,Type,Value)
mat
testmat <- matrix(c("y","x","b","a"),ncol=2)
testmat <- data.frame(testmat)
testmat

test <- inner_join(mat,testmat,by = c("City"="X1", "Type"="X2"))
```

How come when I try to use the inner_join function it gives me a warning message. Here is the warning message that I get....

`In inner_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
  joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector`

This is the desired output, is...

```
    City Type Value
1    y    b    10
2    x    a     1
3    x    a     3
4    x    a     2
5    x    a     5
6    x    a    11
```

but it is producing...

```
    City Type Value
1    x    a     1
2    x    a     3
3    x    a     2
4    x    a     5
5    y    b    10
6    x    a    11
```

I want the inner_join function to produce the values in which they are presented first in the testmat, as shown above. So if since City "y" of type "b" comes first in the testmat I want it to come first in the values for "test"

Comment: Have you tried `match`.  Perhaps `df1[,3][match(paste0(testmat[,1], testmat[,2]), do.call(paste0, df1[-3]))]`

Comment: Yup I couldn't figure out how to use match properly.I tried                              x1 <- mat[cbind(match(testmat[,1],City),match(testmat[,2],Type))]

Comment: It is just `paste(.., collapse='')`

Comment: Or `merge(df,testmat,by=1:2)`

Comment: @A.Webb thank you for the help

Comment: I would also suggest to take a look at the [development version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) of `data.table` which have a similar syntax as `dplyr` but using *binary join*. For example, `library(data.table) ; setDT(testmat)[mat, on = c(X1 = "City", X2 = "Type"), nomatch = 0L]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg if you answer it as a question I will accept it and I will give you the bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to just switch the order of testmat and mat, like so..

```
test <- inner_join(testmat,mat,by = c("X1"="City", "X2"="Type"))
```

I find it interesting that the order of the `by` parameter needs to be in the same order of the data frames being passed throught the `innerjoin` function.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is because R treats string vectors as factor type. you can change this behaviour by running the following code at the start of your script:

```
 options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to second part:
The warning states, that you try to join on two factors with different levels. Therefor, the variables are coerced into "character" before joining, theres no problem with that. As Mostafa Rezaei mentioned in his answer R is coercing factors from character-vectors when creating a dataframe. Usually it's best to leave characters:

```
mat <- data.frame(City,Type,Value, stringsAsFactors=F)
testmat <- data.frame(testmat, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Concerning your real question:

The order of the result of a join is not defined. If order is crucial to you, you can use an additional sorting variable:

```
mat %>% 
mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
semi_join(testmat, by = c("City"="X1", "Type"="X2")) %>%
arrange(rn)
```

btw: I think your looking for an semi_join rather than an inner_join, read the help file for differences.